# Nested tables using CSS

Tags: html, css

I know it is very simple question but I am not designer and so I am having problems achieve this.

I have attached the screenshot here of what i expect to make using `<table>` tags.

[image]

Comment: look for the word `colspan`

Answer (score 2):

You should have search for this :D

What you are looking is [Colspan Rowspan](http://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/) properties

Simple example how it works

```html
<table border=1 width=100%>
<tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td><td rowspan=2>Cell 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 4</td><td>Cell 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Html for nested tables and Css for styling the tables and cell borders. Something like this:

```
<table class="table demo-table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="table demo-table2">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And Css:

```
.demo-table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:table;
}

.demo-table td {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Look at the rendered table [here](https://jsfiddle.net/trgqpnoy/)